# copy xml files from src/ to class/ when compile using maven

Tags: java, maven-2

may i know how to copy xml files from rc/  to class/ when compile using maven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put 'em under src/main/resources, it will "just work".  See [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).